# Efficient number reading in Haskell

Tags: performance, parsing, haskell

I'm looking for an efficient way to read numbers from a text file **without installing additional packages**. `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.readInt` seems to do the trick for integers. I've read that `ByteString` now has a `readDouble` method, but when I write `import Data.ByteString.Lex.Lazy.Double (readDouble)` the compiler complains:

```
    Main.hs:4:7:
        Could not find module `Data.ByteString.Lex.Lazy.Double':
          locations searched:
            Data/ByteString/Lex/Lazy/Double.hs
            Data/ByteString/Lex/Lazy/Double.lhs
```

My bytestring package version is 0.9.1.5.

So, am I doing something wrong? Or maybe there is a better solution for the problem? Thanks.

Update: OK, seems that `readDouble` is in package bytestring-lexer which is not installed by default. Any other idea?

Comment: just install the bytestring-lexer package then. "cabal install bytestring-lexer"

Comment: I want to do without additional packages, because my programs will be run on servers over which I have no control.

Comment: @adamax: It's worth adding that restriction to your question.

Comment: Huh? It's written in the first line. OK, I'll make it bold :)

Comment: "cabal unpack bytestring-lexing" -- now you have the source for the bytestring-lexing package. Drop it in your source tree, and now you don't need the package! Magic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only time I encountered parsing doubles on the critical path, I used this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.C.String
import System.IO.Unsafe

foreign import ccall unsafe "stdlib.h atof" c_atof :: CString -> IO CDouble
unsafeReadDouble = unsafePerformIO . flip B.useAsCString c_atof
```

There wasn't anything that looked like a `readDouble` in bytestring at that time, though.  That would probably be a better solution if it's now standard.

Comment: Thanks! I've made some experiments. To make things easier, I took atoi instead of atof and compared it with the usual show function and my naive implementation (iread). FFI totally beats show, however it loses about 20% to iread. Perhaps, there is an overhead caused by conversions to CString

Answer (score 5):

Another solution: install the [bytestring-lexing](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-lexing) package, and use `readDouble`, which I optimized for you.

```
 cabal install bytestring-lexing
```

The package provides [optimized parsing functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring-lexing/0.2.1/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lex-Double.html) for floating point literals:

```
 readDouble :: ByteString -> Maybe (Double, ByteString)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with.

I used the function offered by JB and added two tricks which I learned from the source code of bytestring-lexing (thanks, sclv!). The first one is this function:

```
strict = SB.concat . LB.toChunks
```

It transforms a lazy bytestring into non-lazy one efficiently.

The second trick is function `Data.ByteString.Internal.inlinePerformIO` which is a more efficient variant of unsafePerformIO.

Here's complete code that allows a pretty fast number reading:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB
import qualified Data.ByteString as SB
import Data.ByteString.Internal (inlinePerformIO)
import Foreign.C.String (CString)
import Foreign.C (CDouble)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

foreign import ccall unsafe "stdlib.h atof" c_atof :: CString -> IO Double
unsafeReadDouble = inlinePerformIO . flip SB.useAsCString c_atof
{-# INLINE unsafeReadDouble #-}
readDouble = unsafeReadDouble . SB.concat . LB.toChunks
readInt = fst . fromJust . LB.readInt
```

And a sample program that calculates the sum of all numbers in the input:

`main = LB.getContents >>= (print . sum . map readDouble . LB.lines)`

It processes an 11Mb file (1M numbers) in about 0.5 seconds

I also [found](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/SPOJ#Enormous_Input%3a_Solutions_to_INTEST) [several](http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg63973.html) [links](http://groups.google.com/group/fa.haskell/browse_thread/thread/4133fa71ce97eb0e/fef34d1c3943bbe0#fef34d1c3943bbe0), where a much more efficient version of `readInt` is discussed. Presumably one can build a `readDouble` based on similar ideas. But I think I'll stick with my current version for now.